# Coding a Flexible HTML Sports Bracket

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a bracket system using HTML. I've found other solutions, however, most require lots of absolute/relative positioning or tables.

I'm looking for a way to make it flexible, so I can just change the HTML to change it from a 16-man bracket to a 64-man bracket.

[404 - link removed]

Now, I don't see much wrong with my current example, however, I'm just curious if there is anyone out there has some suggestions on improving or completely changing the way I am doing it.

I'd rather stay away from tables, and definitely stay away from any sort of positioning (this is meant to be flexible).

If you have any ideas, that would be great. :)

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: I'm doing something similar and would really like to see this code as well. However, the link seems broken. Would you mind pasting the code onto your post here on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 2):

That actually looks fairly good. What I would do to improve it is encapsulate the logic in a bit of Javascript, supply the bracket information in some sort of text format, and have the Javascript parse the text format to generate the bracket as deeply as you need it.

Comment: That's basically what I will be doing, however, I think I'll use Ruby on Rails to handle the logic, as this will be an app coded with RoR. Thanks for the comment. I think with some small cleanup, this might be  my final draft.

Comment: I'll second this - your existing html looks pretty good to me.