# Tournament bracket

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML to create tournament final four bracket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262022/html-to-create-tournament-final-four-bracket)

How would I display a tournament bracket flexibly and semantically? [image: A figure I made to show what I mean]

I mean something like that, except it should work with 32 or 64 starting teams too. I'd like to do this without images if possible. Thank you.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262022/html-to-create-tournament-final-four-bracket and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181703/drawing-a-tournament-bracket-css-html-based-on-php-dataset and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668694/coding-a-flexible-html-sports-bracket

Comment: Do you have any thoughts or code to share?